# Gradle Create a kotlin compile task

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am in the process of creating a gradle plugin that should generate some code using some annotation processors. If working with java we can register a task of type `JavaCompile` and pass the annotation processor as an argument. In this case for a multi-modules project we can register  a task for each module.

I am wondering if this it is possible to do for `kotlin` files. I can find `KotlinCompile` task but I can figure out  how to configure it.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Comment: The `KotlinCompile` compile task needs to be created with `kotlin.target.compilations.create`. Refer answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78088273/10435528